# discord.client logging in using static token

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py, token

I have a problem, since starting my bot lately, I keep getting this one error message, I have no real idea what this error could mean. I also tried to reset my bot-token and made a new bot, but nothing is changed since then. Especially what does static token mean, I had looked up that word but found nothing, would be very happy about helpful answers.

The Error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Löpold\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 59, in <module>
    bot.run(token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 304, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001F03CF823A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed```
````

And thats my original code:

```
import json
import asyncio
import datetime
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from io import BytesIO

from numpy import resize


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=discord.Intents.all())
prefix = "."





async def status_task():
    while True:
        await client.change_presence(
            activity=discord.Activity(
                type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
                name="Leon"),
            status=discord.Status.online)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

        await client.change_presence(
            activity=discord.Activity(
                type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
                name=f"A master at work"),
            status=discord.Status.online)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)


@client.command()
async def helps(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="E", description=f"""
`███████╗██████╗ ██████╗  ██████╗ ██████╗ 
██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗
█████╗  ██████╔╝██████╔╝██║   ██║██████╔╝
██╔══╝  ██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║   ██║██╔══██╗
███████╗██║  ██║██║  ██║╚██████╔╝██║  ██║
╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝`

""", color=discord.Colour.blue(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), inline="true")
    embed.set_footer(icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
async def createchannel(ctx, channelName):
    guild = ctx.guild

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Succesfully created a new Channel", description="{} has been created".format(channelName))
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_channels:
        await guild.create_text_channel(name='{}'.format(channelName))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)



client.run('')
```

I have no clue what the problem is, can maybe someone help me.

Comment: I tried to start it online via replit.com, but to no avail, the same error message came up as before.

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1001907089951694858/1014577785416716408/unknown.png?width=812&height=905

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the string you have passed is not a valid token. Please check if your token is correct. If you forgot your token you can create a new one at your [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Answer (score 0):

401 Error means you're unauthorized. If you haven't updated your environment variables with your new keys, I would do that. Other than that try restarting your terminal

Comment: Do you mean the System Variables from Windows, then i already to that?

Comment: Typically you'll have an .env file in your file structure to your project where you add your bot keys, and reference them when necessary. Read (https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) on how to handle authorization requests